# How to silence training info in GluonTS / Apache mxnet?

Tags: python, mxnet

When I train my DeepAREstimator in GluonTS

```py
estimator = DeepAREstimator(freq="D", 
                              prediction_length=56, 
                              trainer=Trainer(epochs=20))

predictor = estimator.train(training_data=training_data)
```

I get a bunch of debug messages:

```
INFO:root:Epoch[12] Learning rate is 0.001
100%|██████████| 50/50 [00:09<00:00,  5.31it/s, avg_epoch_loss=2.29]
INFO:root:Epoch[12] Elapsed time 9.422 seconds
INFO:root:Epoch[12] Evaluation metric 'epoch_loss'=2.293711
INFO:root:Epoch[13] Learning rate is 0.001
```

How can I silence these? It might have to do with the underlaying mxnet so I tag that as well. Can someone add the gluonts tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging

logging.getLogger("mxnet").addFilter(lamda record: False)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'disable'. I do logging.getLogger('mxnet').disabled = True but it doesn't work

Comment: I do logging.getLogger().disabled = True but I still get some: 0%|          | 0/50 [00:00<?, ?it/s]learning rate from ``lr_scheduler`` has been overwritten by ``learning_rate`` in optimizer.
100%|██████████| 50/50 [00:08<00:00,  5.57it/s, avg_epoch_loss=-.0588]

Comment: can you try logging.getLogger("mxnet").addFilter(lamda record: False)

Comment: logging.getLogger("mxnet").addFilter(lambda record: False)  
(minor typo)